# Windows7 Batch, how to break after first For loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, terminal

I'm writing a simple script to retreive my localhost address given as IP.

To get my IPv4 address (Win7) I've written simple FOR loop, but as a result i get the IP from **last loop** instead of **first one**.

Here is the batch code:

```
cls
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do (
  set ip=%%b
)
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo %ip%
```

this returns:

```
(set ip= 192.168.1.101 )
(set ip= 192.168.88.1 )
(set ip= 192.168.137.1 )
set ip=192.168.137.1
echo 192.168.137.1
192.168.137.1
```

What i need is the result of first loop:

```
192.168.1.101
```

Comment: After the `set` command in the loop, place `goto :SKIP`; put the label `:SKIP` after the closing `)` of the loop...

Comment: Yes, it required adding :SKIP label right after the loop and did the job :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this code without any loop ?

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do (set IP=%%a)
Echo The IP adress is : %IP%
pause
```

Comment: Tested - working. Since @aschipfl also suggested solution, your is shorter one, I will mark it as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also code with @aschipfl `:SKIP` solution

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do (
  set ip=%%b
  goto :SKIP
)
:SKIP
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo %ip%
```